# SMPS Layout, capacitors in parallel placement

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, layout

I'm laying out a buck converter based on the [TPS54308](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54308.pdf), and the datasheet recommends the following, which I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

Webench (the interactive design tool by TI), however, recommends 2 large MLCC (2*10uF) on the input instead of only 1 large cap.

So I have two options, leave 10uF + 100nF close to the TPS54308 and another 10uF further away, which keeps the loop quite compact:

[image]

Or I place all the input caps together (2*10uF + 100nF), which tends to make the loop apparently much larger:

[image]

Is this likely to have any real-world impact at all? Is any of the options better than the other? I mean, both will work, but if there is one that is better I would prefer to know.

Comment: It's all up to capacitors strays and pcb layout... different technologies paralleled always call for extra attention, parallel resonance might rise seen impedance at some "in use" frequency and it might be damped enough or not. This can be no issue, but then I'd rather stick to known working good capacitors, down to supplier and part number. This cannot that easy when giving out boards for assembly. So, my personal opinion, I'd be more relaxed with two identical ceramic capacitors.

Comment: @carloc - I plan to use all MLCCs/X7R which I've used in other SMPS before with a bit tougher requirements. It's just that this time I figured I'd ask a question about layouts that I tend to just assume its safe enough.

Comment: High ESR caps will be your friend, because they might have adequate losses (ESR) to be self-damening. Usa Rdamp = sqr(L/C) , thus 10nH and 10uF needs sqrt(1e-8/1e-5) or sqrt(1e-3) or 0.031 ohms (31 milliOhms). That is an awkward value: not available in SMT, and larger than lotta ESR values; also the ESR changes with brand and voltage and temperature. Welcome to the world of "power filter design".

Answer (score 4):

The capacitance between SW node and everything else is charged and discharged on every cycle, which wastes energy and emits noise. So you should minimize that capacitance. If the layout in the appnote suggests routing SW node down a layer with vias so it has maximum capacitance, then the layout in the appnote is retarded and you should ignore it.

Here's a finger-painted improvement:

[image]

This minimizes the area of the hot loop.

Note you should not push the inductor away to place your caps, because that increases the area (and capacitance) of the SW node. Instead put the inductor on top as I did, and you have plenty of space on the left for the caps.

Also all the GND vias are in the same spot, which minimizes the amount of HF current noise injected into your ground plane.

Comment: Double VIAs to inductor at the furthest point from switch?! That threw me off too. But I think whoever wrote the datasheet was in turn bummed by the pinout. A simple swap of GND and SW pins would lend itself for really easy and compact layout

Comment: Yes the pinout is not optimum lol

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

"Is this likely to have any real-world impact at all? Is any of the options better than the other? I mean, both will work, but if there is one that is better I would prefer to know."

The decoupling capacitors are used to store charge so that in the event of a high dI/dt event at the load your input supply doesn't droop too much or collapse. For example in processors if there's too much of a droop that can lead to a blue screen.

Therefore, the "real-world" impact really depends on how your load is behaving and how sensitive your load is to input supply noise. Unless it's high speed I/O designs or the dI/dt at the load is really big (big is related to your max load and the time it takes to reach that i.e. 1A/10nS). Otherwise you will not see a whole lot of practical problems.

That's why the datasheets specify the minimum operating voltage of certain things as well, so that if you're operating at Vmin and there's a droop event, you might lose your system.